# DiscordJs v14 create a message error includes

Tags: discord.js, bots

I don't understand why i have this error i want create a bot for add role if a people write link in description but the code don't want get my includes
`

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config');

const bot = new Client({ 
    intents: [3276799]
});

bot.commands = new Collection()

require('./src/Structure//Handler/Event')(bot);
require('./src/Structure//Handler/Command')(bot);

bot.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("1048286446345261137");
    const member = newPresence.member
    const activities = newPresence.activities[0];
    if (activities && (activities.state.includes(".gg/slayde" ) || activities.state.includes(".gg/slayde"))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
    } else {
      if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
      }
    }
  })

bot.login(config.clients.token);
```

`

The error

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')`

I try to fix but i'm blocked

Comment: `activities.state` is returning `null`. Try to log `activities` and see what it's coming

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Activity?scrollTo=state), the `state` property of `Activity` is optional (`?string`), which means it doesn't always have a value. You have to make sure it exists before you call `includes()` on it.

```js
if (activities && activities.state && (activities.state.includes(".gg/slayde" ) || activities.state.includes(".gg/slayde"))) {
  // etc
}
```